# AngularJS - Hiding value based on null and empty array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-show, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

I am trying to perform an ng-hide when a value is either null or an empty array (in Firebug, this appears as []).

I can carry out the null via:

```
ng-hide="myData.Address == null"
```

However when i try:

```
ng-hide="myData.Address == null || myData.Address == []"
```

The value still appears.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-hide="myData.Address == null || myData.Address.length == 0"
```

Answer (score 4):

null  and [] are both false, a shorter and cleaner way

```
ng-show="myData.Address"
```

Comment: Not true, `[]` is not falsy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-hide="!myData.Address || !myData.Address.length"
```